# How to crop image centre as per aspect ratio using canvas drawimage function react native

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, canvas

I have a portrait image and I want to crop a part of it from center like 16:9 aspect ratio/or any other way, I did other things like placing on canvas and all, I just want the dynamic coordinates of it because testing on other mobile devices gives me different result.
example first image is original image and below that is crop image which I want[image: original image]
[image: after crop]

Comment: Do you want to get the dimensions of the image?

Comment: @MohammadrezaGolshahi No, I want the dynamic parameters that needs to passed in order to get the above cropped image

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to set the a heigit to the image and background-position?

```
img{
  height: 400px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: I want actual Image to get cropped, not just showing it to be cropped, that's why  I am using canvas element.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this, using the padding-top property on the parent?

```css
div.container {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  position: relative;
}

div.container img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
   <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9B7U.jpg" alt="">
 </div>
```

Comment: As I told that I am using canvas like html, so I don't want to just show the image cropped, I want to actually crop the image and place it on canvas and send it to api.